# Nautical prepositions for " Toward the port /starboard / bow / stern " of a ship

Tags: prepositions

If one thing is to the 'aft' of a second thing, it is 'abaft' the second thing.

For example, the captain's cabin is abaft the gun deck.

Are there similar words for other ship directions, such as 'bow', 'port', and 'starboard'?

Comment: For *bow*, the corresponding term is *forward*. For the direction in which the wind is blowing (the direction the sails are billowing), *leeward*, and its antonym, *windward*. The words *port* and *starboard* can be used directly.

Comment: The classical command to "tack" a sailboat is "Hard alee!", which means to push the tiller all the way to the leeward (downwind) side of the craft.  I'm pretty sure "awind" may be used in the opposite sense.  (But note that these terms refer to the position of the tiller, and pushing the tiller leeward turns the craft windward.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding terms would be

- afore (towards the front/bow)
- aport
- astarboard
- astern

See [glossary of nautical terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_nautical_terms) on Wikipedia.

Comment: It might be worth incorporating the comment on *alee* into this answer. And the general observation: 'a-' is a common prefix used to create many nautical prepositions....

Comment: @JeremyDouglass A sailor might  be working aloft or alow.

Answer (score 2):

> For bow, the corresponding term is *forward*. For the direction in which the wind is blowing (the direction the sails are billowing), *leeward*, and its antonym, *windward*. The words *port* and *starboard* can be used directly.
>   — Dan Bron